# paper-ripple inside paper-item inside paper-menu animation

Tags: polymer

I got a weird problem with the paper-ripple inside a paper-item in a paper-menu. Given: I have 5 menu items. And: I click the 2nd item. Then: The paper-ripple inside the 5th paper-item animates And: I click once again on the 2nd item. Then the 4th paper-ripple inside it’s wrapping paper-item animates. And: I click again on the 2nd item. Then: the 3rd item animates. it’s kinda weird and I can’t figure out why that’s happening. Anyone with the same problem here?

```
<dom-module id="menu-element">
  <template>
    <paper-menu class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu}}">
        <a data-route$="{{item.route}}" href="{{item.href}}">
          <paper-item>
            <iron-icon icon$="{{item.icon}}" item-icon></iron-icon>
            <paper-item-body>
              <span>{{item.text}}</span>
            </paper-item-body>
            <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
          </paper-item>
        </a>
      </template>
    </paper-menu>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Chances are you need to put a `position: relative` or something like that on your paper-item. Can you provide an example of what your items array looks like.

Comment: Thanks endy! That seemed to be the problem indeed!